# When did sharing beds with strangers in inns/hotels start to decline?

Tags: united-states, travel

Hard to believe this ever happened -- and maybe it didn't but I have read about it in Moby Dick, for example --but I am wondering how long this lasted? The closest I have ever come to this was a semi-private (that is, shared with one other room) bathroom in England and I frankly did not like this. Sharing a bed with a stranger would be crazy but maybe it still happens in parts of the world, so I am asking about the USA.

Comment: Sharing *bedrooms* is still quite common in hostels - a dormitory style room can have anything from 2 to 20 beds in it, although they're usually only inhabited by one person (although I've been in hostel dorms where some beds were... noisy)

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan: Sure and people share bedrooms in dorms; but I wonder if there is a single commercial establishment in the entire USA where one would be offered a bed with a complete stranger to share. Some less-industrialized nations, perhaps, but this would just blow away an American.

Comment: i would think that the first question to ask is whether the practice was ever actually common in America. Measuring the decline of something that was a rarity in the first place may be something of a challenge.

Comment: @Steve Bird: My guess is that it was pretty common -- what are considered requirements today were great luxuries at one time. I doubt if even Vanderbilt had indoor plumbing in 1850s Manhattan.

Comment: [*Moby-Dick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby-Dick) starts with one shared bedroom and bed in an inn.

Comment: @Jeff Chaucer's pilgrims may have shared beds - not sure about that.

Comment: @Brasidas, the Wiki page does state that the *"inn where he arrives is so crowded, he must share a bed with the tattooed Polynesian Queequeg"*, which implies that this was an exceptional circumstance, rather than the normal state of operation. It may well have simply been just a literary device to introduce Queequeg's character.

Comment: @WS2 - Most of the stories in Canterbury Tales that involve sharing beds don't involve a lot of sleeping.

Comment: @SteveBird, if I remember well the book, Ishmael the protagonist has no problem in sharing the bed, it's only he is afraid of Queequeg, a fearsome character and "a savage". The book gives the impression that sharing the bed wasn't that exceptional: today this would end with a 1-star review at Tripadvisor.

Comment: BTW, somehow I didn't notice that Moby Dick was already mentioned in the question. Silly me.

Comment: I am somewhat intrigued by this "semi-private bathroom in England", and what that might have to do with sharing beds. Were you required to share the bath?

Comment: @WS2 not simultaneously

Comment: Are there any examples of this happening other than in a work of fiction?

Comment: IIRC, Adams shared a bed with someone - can't remember who - during the constitutional convention. A visit to Colonial Williamsburg will also generate discussion of this.  It was common, I just can't say when it stopped.

Comment: [Adams and Franklin](http://mentalfloss.com/article/54169/time-ben-franklin-and-john-adams-shared-bed) >In September 1776, just a few months after the thirteen American colonies announced their independence from Britain, Benjamin Franklin and John Adams got stuck shacking up together for a night.

Comment: [Madison shares a bed](https://books.google.com/books?id=__paDQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT97&ots=u8l38-KRGX&dq=adams%20constitutional%20convention%20rooms%20share%20bed&pg=PT97#v=onepage&q=share%20bed&f=false)

Comment: I think it wasn't that big of deal. I think there must have been hundreds of little details like that in those days that might shock a modern person.